# How Do I Configure IIS FTP 7.5 Passive Ports Per-FTP Site? (Setting appears locked at the server level)

Tags: configuration, ftp, iis-7.5, ftps

I am needing to use the functionality to set the FTP PASV port range that IIS FTP7.5 will use, but it seems this is locked down in configuration at the server level; I can not modify the port range per-site. (I can modify the IP address but not the port range on each site via the manager, but I can modify both at the server level)

[image: Per-site screen]

My assumption is that this is locked down in the configuration somewhere, but I'm not sure where to look. It does *not* appear to be amongst the options under 'Feature Delegation', by the way.

I'm having to use this because the system in question is running FTPS and is behind an iptables-managed firewall; the state/conntrack modules can *not* help in this case because the firewall is incapable of inspecting the FTPS packets, since they are encrypted.

I would prefer to be able to specify this port range per site, as one of the sites will only need a very narrow range, while another will need a somewhat broader range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the directions I followed for configuring that

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/309/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings/

Go to the firewall settings after clicking on the SERVER not the site

Comment: That's not what I want to do. I want to edit it per-site, not on the whole server. The option is there - it just seems to be locked down in the config somewhere, and I'm not sure where.

Comment: There isn't a way to do it per site. It is a per server setting otherwise you will have to deal with port forwarding ranges of ports for multiple Sites. You set it globally for IIS

Comment: Well, I just spent 40 minutes playing with web.config files and the `firewallSupport` element and indeed, it can only be altered per-server rather than per-site! Voted/Accepted your answer; thank you!